# Django restframework - how to combine two queryset to Serialize in order of priority?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

This is my original query:
             `Movie.objects.filter(releaseday__gte=past_month.date(),releaseday__lte=today.date(),movie__movietime__gte=today).extra({'vrank': 'CASE WHEN hotrank=0 THEN 4 WHEN hotrank >=4 THEN 4 ELSE hotrank END'}).distinct().order_by('vrank','-releaseday')`

But the result has duplicate.
I look the document,it said that the proble is use `order_by()` and `distinct()` together

So now I need to combine `queryset1` and `queryset2` in sequence. 
Show the result of `queryset1` first,
then `queryset2`
Please help me thank you

views.py:

```
class MovieList(MovieMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get("top"):
            self.top(top)
        return super(MovieList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def top(self,top):    
        queryset1 = Movie.objects.filter(releaseday__gte=past_month.date(),releaseday__lte=today.date(),movie__movietime__gte=today,hotrank__lte=3).exclude(hotrank=0).distinct().order_by('hotrank')
        queryset2 = Movie.objects.filter(releaseday__gte=past_month.date(),releaseday__lte=today.date(),movie__movietime__gte=today).exclude(hotrank__lte=3,hotrank__gte=1).distinct().order_by('-releaseday')

        self.queryset =( queryset1 | queryset2 )
```

Comment: I make it simple.original query is longer. I will edit it .wait for a while

Comment: By "combine", do you mean "union"? That is, you want all items that are members of one or both of the input querysets.

Comment: why not introduce a variable for common filtering? `q_common = Q(releaseday__gte=past_month.date(),releaseday__lte=today.date(),movie__movietime__gte=today)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
from itertools import chain
....
self.queryset = sorted(chain(queryset1, queryset2),
    key=lambda instance: instance.releaseday)
```

This will combine queryset1 and queryset2 and then sort them by the value `realaseday`.

Comment: I have error:````'list' object has no attribute '_clone'````

Comment: I think this returns a list. So you cant use it as a queryset any more.

Comment: If you want a queryset, then you can try `final_queryset =( queryset1 | queryset2 )`. Then `self.queryset = final_queryset.order_by('releaseday')`.

Comment: thank you.But I still have to ````order_by('hotrank')````. My rules is order the top 3 hot movies,then order the other movies by releaseday. I don't know how to order this in final_queryset

Comment: How do you get top three movies?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that. Sorting a part of a queryset.

Comment: ````queryset1````  is top 3 movies

Comment: if I just ````return  sorted(chain(queryset1, queryset2),
    key=lambda instance: instance.releaseday)```` ,it will get all movies in db. if I use ````self.queryset = sorted(chain(queryset1, queryset2),
    key=lambda instance: instance.releaseday)````,I will get error : ````'list' object has no attribute '_clone'````

Comment: Because chain will return a list. Not a queryset. That is the problem.